# When i use Scanner in my code then my program only in running state it not completed

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, coderunner

Whenever i use Scanner is this program, the program goes to running state it is not completed, if it is completed then its input not working. But when i remove it successfully working. I don't know what happening in my vscode.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/390Hr.png)

Firstly i tried Scanner but its not working then i remove scanner and manually entered number then its worked.'

Comment: please include the code as text (code formatted) into the question - check [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C82.2483)

Comment: Keep in mind your program is going to wait for a user-input.  This isn't related to the command-line arguments.  So, you'll have to enter a number, in the _output console_ there.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows that you are using **Code Runner** to execute the script, and now it outputs the result in the **OUTPUT** panel, but the **OUTPUT** panel cannot accept input.

- You can add the following setting to make the result output in the **TERMINAL** panel

  ```
      "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  ```
- The best solution is to use the official java extension package to execute the script.

  [image]

  [image]

  *`Run Java` instead of `Run Code`*